Fetch Previous State In Gorm V2 Callback
I am trying to query for the previous state of the row in a callback.
I've registered the callback as such:
callback.Update().Before("gorm:save_before_associations").Replace("before_update", beforeUpdate)

In the function I would like to query for the previous state of the row but struggle to extract the where clause the query is using.
func beforeUpdate(db *gorm.DB) {
    modelType := reflect.TypeOf(db.Statement.ReflectValue.Interface())
    valueBefore := reflect.New(modelType).Interface()

    // here I would like to assemble the where clause and query
}

Inside of the function I do have access to the components of the where clause through db.Statement.Clauses["WHERE"] but am not certain on how to build the clause using GORM.
I assumed that there would be a function similar to build the combined where clause
